# How to get size of desktop exclusive of "System Tray"in Swing

Tags: java, swing

How would I calculate the size of the desktop, exclusive of the System Tray, in Swing?  I want to size my app's frame to fill that size. `Toolkit.getScreenSize()` returns the size including the system tray.

Comment: Do you mean the taskbar?

Comment: Nothing complicated.  Just trying to open the main frame taking up all the screen area exclusive of the system tray.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
GraphicsEnvironment env = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
Rectangle bounds = env.getMaximumWindowBounds();
frame.setMaximizedBounds(bounds);
```

Comment: I am accepting this answer although it is not quite complete for me.  Because of the "multitude of sins" already baked into this GUI, it is necessary to set the preferred size of the root pane.  But thanks all the same, because getRootPane().setPreferredSize(env.getMaximumWindowBounds().getSize()) does the trick.  That was the API I was looking for.

Comment: @SteveCohen, I will try that in my case too.

Comment: I've unaccepted this answer because it isn't quite right.  env.getMaximumWindowBounds() does return the size of the desktop less the taskbar, but I still need to set the preferred size of the Root Pane, and I need to subtract the horizontal and vertical insets for the frame border, which I don't seem to be able to get until the thing is made visible.  Where does one learn the size of the frame border?  I don't see this in the UI defaults, which is where I presume it must come from.

Comment: OK, reaccepted it now.  Duh, I can call setPreferredSize() on the Frame.  Not sure why I thought I had to do it on the root pane.  I guess because it's not a JComponent - but it's still a Component.  What does the trick is frame.setPreferredSize(env.getMaximumWindowBounds());

Answer (score 1):

So you want to set the application to full screen, is it? In that case, do a:

```
frame.setExtendedState(Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
```

Comment: Well, I didn't write this code.  The call to frame.setExtendedState(Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH) was already there.  But without an explicit setPreferredSize() on the root pane, it is showing up taking up much less than the whole desktop.  I was calling setPreferredSize() using Toolkit.getScreenSize().  This "worked" except it ran roughshod over the system tray.  So I thought that if I could calculate the size I wanted this would work.  Undoubtedly there are a multitude of sins in the GUI, but it appears that this would at least paper them over. :-)

Answer (score 1):

To set the Swing application JFrame to maximized, use the following:

```
frame.setExtendedState(frame.getExtendedState() | Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
```

To get the size of the maximized frame, use the following:

```
GraphicsEnvironment env = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
Rectangle bounds = env.getMaximumWindowBounds();
```